# How to change symbol size in QGIS map composer legend?

Tags: qgis, symbology, legend

I need to set an identical size to several symbols inside a QGIS map composer legend. The 'Symbol' menu in the Legend properties allows to set a height and width but this has no effect on the size of the symbols in the legend...

Here is an example of my legend automatically taking symbols sizes from layers:[image]

**EDIT :** For now, I solved the problem by cloning my layers. Inside each cloned layer, I keep just one record to which I set the symbol size I need in the composer. Then, I build my legend in the composer that uses theses cloned layers. This is just a stopgap solution and I really would like to know if a more direct way does exist with QGIS.

Comment: The method you used is the easiest way and the way i would recommend. Works for Argis too ;)  You can use a group to distinguish the legend items and the map items if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for anyone that may still be looking around for an answer to this issue, I havent managed to find a feature within QGIS either... but i have figured an effective way of compensating for the issue.

I simply add an image box into the Print Composer and use an corresponding image (Usually .SVG files) to cover the previous symbol that is too small. I understand its not the best way to get around the issue but its much quicker than creating and duplicating layers.

I hope this helps anyone with similar issues.

Answer (score 4):

Since QGIS 3.14 you can change the change symbol in the legend.

In the layout select your legend, go to item property, then double click on the legend item you want to edit.

Check the `custom symbol` checkbox and by double clicking on it you can configure the size or color or symbol that would be used in the legend only.

[image]

Note : If needed you can find information on how to [display polygon as a line](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/401014/display-polygon-as-a-line-in-legend/401018#401018)

Comment: This is the best and simplest way still (in QGIS 3.16). Here's a quick step by step:
1. click legend item on layout    
2. view **Item Properties**    
3. double click on the legend item that contains the symbol you're trying to change. This brings up the **Legend Items Properties** box    
4. find the **Custom Symbol** section    
5. enable Custom symbol, then create it in the size shape and colour you prefer

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is still no solution to adjust the symbol size of point features inside the QGIS composer. The symbol entry works only for polygons and lines.

However, a workaround that was not mentioned yet is to export the map as an svg-file and open it with Inkscape for example (Inkscape is open source). There you can manually adjust the symbol size for every legend item.