# Display polygon as a line in legend

Tags: qgis, polygon, line, legend

I am trying to edit the admin boundary legend in the attached picture from a polygon to a line. However, when I do this by editing the symbol width and height, it changes for both the admin and R2 legend. But I just want this for only the admin legend. How do I go about this?   [image]

Comment: Duplicate the layer or create a new scratch layer, make the admin boundary a line (e.g. via geometry generator), make it invisible in the map and add it to the legend.

Comment: It worked!!!  Thank you!!!

Comment: It should also work if you changed your polygon symbology from `simple fill` to `border - line`.

Answer (score 4):

There is a very clean solution since QGIS 3.14 ([changelog](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog314/#feature-allow-overriding-the-default-symbol-for-a-legend-node)), you can use a custom symbol in legend or adapt your symbol in many ways.

Here is how to do.

1. In the layout select your legend, go to `item property`, then in `legend item` double click in the item you want to edit.
   [image]
2. Go to `patch` and `configure patch`.
   [image]
3. In the `Shape` text box change the original wkt string `Polygon ((0 5, 10 5, 10 0, 0 0, 0 5))` to be `Polygon ((0 5, 10 5))`.
   [image]

You can also activate custom symbol and use a geometry generator or any styling option to make your legend clean.

My advice is not to make fake layer as they will not work well if you use multi stilling and map themes.

Comment: I agree with you on the fake layers. I can`t find patch  in the legend item. Could it be the version I am using? Am using QGIS 3.4.5

Comment: Yes it is the version, it work in the 3.18.1 that i use and it seems to work since 3.14 https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog314/#feature-allow-overriding-the-default-symbol-for-a-legend-node